# Java - Throwable to Exception

Tags: java, exception, throwable

I am currently using the play2 framework.

I have several classes which are throwing `exceptions` but play2s global `onError` handler uses throwable instead of an exception.

for example one of my classes is throwing a `NoSessionException`. Can I check a throwable object if it is a `NoSessionException` ?

Comment: Throwable is the superclass of all exceptions.  You can `catch` a throwable and then interrogate its class to see if it's a NoSessionException or whatever.

Comment: thank you all for the fast answer.

Comment: Of course, you can also catch specifically NoSessionException, and then pass it to an interface that expects a Throwable -- since Throwable is the superclass the interface will accept NoSessionException.

Comment: (And if you do catch all Throwables, you shouldn't simply ignore the ones you don't select, but rather you should re-throw them.)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` to check it is of `NoSessionException` or not.

Example:

```
if (exp instanceof NoSessionException) {
...
}
```

Assuming `exp` is the `Throwable` reference.

Answer (score 54):

Just make it short. We can pass `Throwable` to `Exception` constructor.

```
 @Override
 public void onError(Throwable e) {
    Exception ex = new Exception(e);
 }
```

See this [Exception](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.Throwable)) from Android

Comment: Stack trace data is lost doing this however  :-(

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Android also provide another constructor to keep the StackTrace.
Exception (String message, 
                Throwable cause, 
                boolean enableSuppression, 
                boolean writableStackTrace)

Answer (score 16):

> Can I check a throwable object if it is a NoSessionException ?

Sure:

```
Throwable t = ...;
if (t instanceof NoSessionException) {
    ...
    // If you need to use information in the exception
    // you can cast it in here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) is a class which `Exception` – and consequently all subclasses thereof – subclasses. There's nothing stopping you from using `instanceof` on a `Throwable`.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to checking if its an `instanceof` you can use the try catch and catch NoSessionException

```
try {
    // Something that throws a throwable
} catch (NoSessionException e) {
    // Its a NoSessionException 
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // catch all other Throwables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring, then why not go for a specific exception handler for specific type.

You can have one GlobalException handler  and tag it to your controller

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {YourController.class})
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler {
```

Then you can have specific handler methods to handle specific exception.

for e.g. below is handling **specific ServerWebInputException**

```
  @ExceptionHandler(ServerWebInputException.class)
      public ResponseEntity<YourResponseObject> handleValidationError(final ServerWebInputException badRequest) {
    }
```

and you can have a generic **Throwable handler**

```
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
  public ResponseEntity<YourResponseObject> handleThrowable(final Throwable throwable) {
```

This would be a clean solution.