# How to check which exception type was thrown in Java?

Tags: java, exception

How can I determine which type of exception was caught, if an operation catches multiple exceptions?

This example should make more sense:

```
try {
  int x = doSomething();
} catch (NotAnInt | ParseError e) {
  if (/* thrown error is NotAnInt */) {    // line 5
    // printSomething
  } else {
    // print something else
  }
}
```

On line 5, how can I check which exception was caught?

I tried `if (e.equals(NotAnInt.class)) {..}` but no luck.

NOTE: `NotAnInt` and `ParseError` are classes in my project that extend `Exception`.

Comment: make sever catches:
catch (NotAnInt) { } catch (ParseError) {}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Throwable to Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359175/java-throwable-to-exception)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you can, *always* use separate `catch` blocks for individual exception types, there's no excuse to do otherwise:

```
} catch (NotAnInt e) {
    // handling for NotAnInt
} catch (ParseError e) {
    // handling for ParseError
}
```

...unless you need to share some steps in common and want to avoid additional methods for reasons of conciseness:

```
} catch (NotAnInt | ParseError e) {
    // a step or two in common to both cases
    if (e instanceof NotAnInt) {
        // handling for NotAnInt
    } else  {
        // handling for ParseError
    }
    // potentially another step or two in common to both cases
}
```

however the steps in common could also be extracted to methods to avoid that `if`-`else` block:

```
} catch (NotAnInt e) {
    inCommon1(e);
    // handling for NotAnInt
    inCommon2(e);
} catch (ParseError e) {
    inCommon1(e);
    // handling for ParseError
    inCommon2(e);
}

private void inCommon1(e) {
    // several steps
    // common to
    // both cases
}
private void inCommon2(e) {
    // several steps
    // common to
    // both cases
}
```

Comment: In which case can't you put multiple catch blocks ? Just curious.

Comment: @Chargnn I was wondering the same. Maybe if the `catch` block was calling some `onException(Exception e)` callback? The other answer is better, IMHO.

Comment: sorry, I made a detrimental edit to the post recently, which I have reverted now (and further improved upon).

Answer (score 27):

If Multiple `throws`  are happening in a single `catch()` then to recognize *which Exception* , you could use **`instanceof`** operator.

The java `instanceof` operator is used to test whether the ***object is an instance*** of the specified type *(class or subclass or interface).*

Try this code :-

```
        catch (Exception e) {
            if(e instanceof NotAnInt){

            // Your Logic.

            } else if  if(e instanceof ParseError){                

             //Your Logic.
            }
      }
```

Comment: And how is that different from what was written in the accepted answer 4 years befire you wrote your answer?

Comment: @GhostCat thank you! There are so many copy-paste posts like these cluttering such questions...

Comment: This answer is different from the accepted (and helpful) because it focuses on one solution, which was tucked away in the example and not mentioned or explained in the answer text. Separate catch blocks did not work for my problem because I was looking at the root cause of a single exception type, so I skimmed those answers.

Comment: This, quite precisely, what I was looking for! I have a multi-catch which, for one exception type only, I want to deviate from the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 16):

Use multiple `catch` blocks, one for each exception:

```
try {
   int x = doSomething();
}
catch (NotAnInt e) {
    // print something
}
catch (ParseError e){
    // print something else
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone didn't know what type of exception was thrown in the method e.g a method with a lot of possibilities like this one :

```
public void onError(Throwable e) {

}
```

You can get the exception class by

```
       Log.e("Class Name", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

In my case it was `UnknownHostException`

then use `instanseof` as mentioned in the previous answers to take some actions

```
public void onError(Throwable e) {
       Log.e("Class Name", e.getClass().getSimpleName());

       if (e instanceof UnknownHostException)
            Toast.makeText(context , "Couldn't reach the server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       else 
          // do another thing
}
```